# How do I setup Mypy with Neomake

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-python, plugin-neomake

I'm trying to use Mypy with Neomake, but without success.
I am currently using flake8 with Neomake, and it works seamlessly, e.g.:

```
def foo(bar):
    return 1

foo(1) > E305 expected 2 blank lines after class or function definition, found 1
```

However, I am not getting warnings from Mypy:

```
def foo(bar: str) -> int:
    return 1


foo(1)
```

where I expect some sort of warnings at `foo(1)`.

When I run Mypy outside of vim, I get an exepcted result:

```
test.py:5: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

The following is the part of my (Neo)vim setting relevant to Neomake / python:

```
" make pyenv work with neovim
let g:python_host_prog = expand('~/.pyenv/versions/neovim-python2/bin/python')
let g:python3_host_prog = expand('~/.pyenv/versions/neovim-python3/bin/python')

" Neomake settings begin
call neomake#configure#automake('nrwi', 500)
" let g:neomake_tex_enabled_makers = ['chktex', 'rubberinfo', 'proselint']
let g:neomake_python_enabled_makers = ['flake8', 'mypy']
let g:neomake_python_flake8_maker = {
  \ 'exe': expand('~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/neovim-python3/bin/flake8'),
  \ 'args': ['--format=default'],
  \ 'errorformat':
      \ '%E%f:%l: could not compile,%-Z%p^,' .
      \ '%A%f:%l:%c: %t%n %m,' .
      \ '%A%f:%l: %t%n %m,' .
      \ '%-G%.%#',
  \ 'postprocess': function('neomake#makers#ft#python#Flake8EntryProcess')
  \ }
let g:neomake_python_mypy_maker = {
  \ 'exe': expand('~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/neovim-python3/bin/mypy'),
  \ }
" Neomake settings end
```

I tried with and without the latter three lines regarding `g:neomake_python_mypy_maker`, but nothing seems to change.
Note that I use pyenv/virtualenv to encapsulate my vim settings.

How can I make Mypy to work within vim?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: I just moved on to Coc.nvim and it works great with all sort of Python static analyzers.